# Number of Linear boolean-functions

Tags: functions, boolean-algebra

How many **linear** boolean functions are there, if we have n variable?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that the [arity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_function) is $n$, then it's $\#\hom_{\mathbb{F}_2}(\mathbb{F}_2^n,\mathbb{F}_2)=\#(\mathbb{F}_2^{n*})=\#(\mathbb{F}_2^n)=2^n$

**Explanation**

- $\#$ is the symbol for the cardinality of a set
- $\mathbb{F}_2$ is the 2-element field (a.k.a. $\{0,1\}$ endowed with sum and product modulo $2$)
- $\hom_{\mathbb{F}_2}(\mathbb{F}_2^n,\mathbb{F}_2)$, or $\mathbb{F}_2^{n*}$, is the set of linear functions from the $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector space $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ to $\mathbb{F}_2$. This set can be identified with the set of $n\times1$ matrixes with entries in $\mathbb{F}_2$, and therefore has exactly $2^n$ elements.

Comment: Yes, n is the arity, but what are these symbols? Can you explain why 2^n is the solution?

Comment: I'll do it. How much are you familiar with vector spaces over a field? @Seasharp

Comment: When we learned about the definition of linear boolean-functions, we didn't involve linear algebra. We just visualized the functions in tables. But anyway, at least now I know the answer, I will be thinking about it. Thanks.